# It appears that while using Selenium with Python on a MacBook Air M1, there are issues with Chrome's automation. Frequent crashing and not interacting

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[Getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhLJq.png)

Even after updating Chrome versions and ChromeDriver, the problem remains with Selenium's inability to interact properly with elements, causing Chrome to crash. I've had to extend sleep times to prevent Chrome from closing. This situation might indicate underlying compatibility issues or conflicts within the setup that need further investigation.

I anticipated that updating the Chrome version and ChromeDriver would resolve the issue with Selenium's interaction with elements, preventing Chrome from crashing. However, it seems that the problem persists, requiring extended sleep times to avoid Chrome closing. This situation suggests deeper compatibility issues or conflicts within the setup that need further investigation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)